# How to Create JavaScript object in QML

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I want to create a global pure JavaScript object. How can I do that?

I tried following

```
//some qml
var gp = { x:0, y:0}
//some qml
```

When I ran this QML file, I get `JavaScript declaration outside Script element`

Answer (score 2):

Declarations in QML should start with `property`. As in:

```
property var gp: { x:0; y:0 }
```

You'll be able to access this from your JS functions. Is that what you're looking for?